# Python - intersection of an array keeping original shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays, made up of 0 and 1, and I'm trying to generate a third array made up of the overlapping 1s. Essentially if my arrays are:

```
array1 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
array2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

then I want the output to be:

```
array_out = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I first tried using `numpy.intersect1d(array1, array2)`, but that just returns `[0,1]`, which isn't keeping the shape. I also tried using `numpy.isin(array1, array2)`, which returns a series of True when the values match and False when they don't. The problem with this is that I cannot tell the difference between places where both arrays had a 0 and where both arrays had a 1.

Both arrays are very large - (256, 256, 256). I also need to run this about 20 times. I did consider using a loop to look at each value individually, but this could take a long time and I was hoping there was a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work ?

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
array2 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
array1*array2
```

This generated

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your arrays are only 1s and 0s, we can also use `np.all` or `np.logical_and`.

```py
import numpy as np

array1 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
array2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

out1 = np.all([array1, array2], axis=0)
print(out1) # [False False False  True False  True False]
print(out1.astype(int)) # [0 0 0 1 0 1 0]

out2 = np.logical_and(array1, array2)
print(out2) # [False False False  True False  True False]
print(out2.astype(int)) # [0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
```